# jquery want to get the immediate next input element in the DOM

Tags: html, jquery, forms

I am using form repeater that basically clones my form. Form has a dropdown and a readonly input field. The input fields value is updated against the value selected from the dropdown.

As I am not managing the IDs in the forms , so cant get the particular input tag against the particular select dropdown.
When I click the add button it adds correctly but if I give class to the input field it changes the values of all the input fields but I only want to change the value of input field that is next to the select of each form-repeater value.

now let me explain [this problem image ][1] attached.

let suppose my form has only select and input as shown in picture, let s ignore the comments and amount field.
Every select option has a value which I need to set in the input field next to it whenever the select value is changed. But the problem is I have given a class to the description input field which also changes the input/placeholder value of all the input fields but I only want to update the input tag that is next to the each select.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-12">
    <div class="mb-1">
        <label class="form-label">Type</label>
        <select class="form-control khataTypeChange" style="color: black" required>
        @foreach ($khataTypes as $khataType)
            <option value="{{ $khataType->id }}">{{ $khataType->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-12">
    <div class="mb-1">
       <label class="form-label">Description</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control description"
       value="{{ $khataTypes[0]->description }}" name="description" required />
       </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$(".khataTypeChange").change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".description").val(myArray [$(this).val() - 1]["description"]);
});
```

P.S : myArray is the array with description which I want to set in the input field on each value selected

What I was trying :

```
$(".khataTypeChange").change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var v = $(this).next("input").val("new value");
    $v.val(myArray[$(this).val() - 1]["description"]);
});
```

NOTE: everytime the add button in the image is pressed it produces the whole new repeated line of elements, so I only need to update the description that is in front of that particular select
I need help , stuck on this for 6 hours :(
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbrXq.png

Comment: can you update the working code here so it is easy to help you?

Comment: thanks for the response , i got it working after spending hours, this is the line of code that is working : `$(this).parent().parent().nextAll().find(".description").val(khataTypeData[$(this).val() - 1]["description"]);`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working with this line :

```
$(this).parent().parent().nextAll().find(".description").val(khataTypeData[$(this).val() - 1]["description"]);
```